# How may I use Bootstrap 5 with Svelte-Kit

Tags: bootstrap-5, sveltekit

I'm trying to use Bootstrap 5 with Svelte-Kit

Following the official documentation at  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/download/ I need to include first popperjs
and then bootstrap 5 css

I'm using

```
<script>
    import "@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.min.js";
    import "bootswatch/dist/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css";
</script>
```

in my  /routes/+layout.svelte file. I'm using the cerulean theme from bootswatch.

The problem is that the css part seems to work but the javascript dependent features (like a dropdown menu) not.

Can you help me?